# How do I select 4 random tables from a mysql database that has thousands of tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I need a fast, efficient way to randomly return to me the names of 4 tables in a single mysql database. The tables DO NOT have a structured naming pattern, except that they are all lowercase letters and numbers.

example:
my_database contains the following tables:

```
(cat, dog, boat, car, cars, cars35, accorns, accerns, speaker, shell, olympics, politics, fray, ttypo, ... (thousands of tables like this) ... , road)
```

I need an efficient way to return the names of a set number of random tables without overlap.

example:

```
function_random_table(4) would return 4 table names stored to the following variables:

$random_1 = cars
$random_2 = cars35
$random_3 = shell
$random_4 = cat
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES:

```
select table_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_DB_NAME'
order by rand()
limit 4
```

Comment: Thanks for teaching me something new about using information schema :)  Good solution.

Comment: I tested the SQL Query in phpmyadmin and it worked perfectly as I wanted it. How do I retrieve those entrise as variables in my php page? I tried the following - didn't work - but you get the idea: $sql = "select table_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database'
order by rand()
limit 4";
$slash = array(mysql_query($sql, $con));
echo $slash[0].$slash[1].$slash[2].$slash[3];

Comment: I'm not an expert on how to receive data from multiple rows in php.  You can, however, use group_concat() to put all of them in single variable.

Comment: Got it: 

$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row[0];
  echo "<br />";  
  }

Comment: //Selects 4 random tables from my_database
    $sql = "select table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' order by rand() limit 4";
    $query = mysql_query($sql, $con);
        
    //create a counting variable and an array to capture the data from the sql
    $i=0;
    $random=array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
          {
          $random[$i]=$row[0];
          $i++;
          }
    echo $random[0].'<br />';
    echo $random[1].'<br />';
    echo $random[2].'<br />';
    echo $random[3].'<br />';

Answer (score 0):

You could put all of your tables in an array. Then generate four random indexes and make sure that they are all unique indexes (so no overlap). Take those indexes and populate your four `$random_n` vars with the positions in the array at those indexes.